# Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php, arrays, grep

I read the php [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) manual and create some code lines.

```
    $handle = fopen("/path/to/file", "a")  or die('Cannot open file:');

    $y= $command_name1.$steps1;
    $x=trim(shell_exec("grep -ri -o '$y' /path/to/file "));
    $Z=array($x);
    if (in_array($y,$z,false))
    {
            echo "thise 2 variables are already in this file";
            fclose($handle);
    }

    else {
    //write some thing on  that file
    }
```

But this gives above error. And I want to know is, can 2 variables(`$command_name1` and `$steps1`)adds together and search it through `in_array` ?.

Comment: $x should be an array. Otherwise it will return this error

Comment: the error explains everything you want to ask for. You just need $x to be an array.

Comment: in_array is an array function coz it has the word "array" in its name. :)

Comment: One would think that error message would be clear enough.. but some people...

Comment: The first rule of program is to read any error message, they are normally self explanatory

Comment: mixing `fopen` with `shell_exec()` with `grep`... I hope that `$command_name1` or `$steps1` isn't comming from users input ($_GET/$_POST) otherwise you have some serious problems ...

Comment: sorry,I just edit the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$x` isn't an array, so you get that error.

[take a look](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to `in_array()` definition and use.

As you can see from function signature

```
bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )
```

you need second argument (in that case `$haystack`) to be an array and not a scalar value (whatever type it is)

Answer (score 2):

`shell_exec()` returns string instead of array, thus `$x` is not an array.

My guess is, OP wants to use `strpos()` instead of `shell_exec()`.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php